# Which is a better way of finding the max of no.s?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

Which is a better way to write a program to find the max of 4 no.s in c/C++:

1. using a fifth variable & comparing it to all inputs
2. using max() function
3. and comparing the inputs using if

or suggest any other, if it has a better approach(in terms of space & time complexity) of solving the problem

Would the same algorithmic approach would still be the best in case of more than 4 variables?

Comment: If you know that it's four inputs, the fewest comparisons is `max(max(a,b), max(c,d))`.

Comment: the comparisons would be few, but wouldn't the space- in terms of the max() function being called repeatedly be more?

Comment: @rlbond: Huh? `max(a, max(b, max(c, d)))` has the same number of comparisons. It just has a longer dependency chain.

Comment: @dj1 What _"space"_ you're talking about?? Meant the "shwitz" or what?

Comment: complexity is usual meant as *asymptotic* complexity, i.e. large `N`

Comment: `std::max({a,b,c,d})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a large number of elements, the Standard Library has the `std::max_element` algorithm which does `max(N-1, 0)` comparisons for `N` elements, which his the theoretical minimum, *even for 4 elements*.

In practice, it loops over all elements as does your method 1., but it could do an "elimination tournament" of nested `max` if `N` is a power of 2 (your method 2). Some optimizing compiler might even unroll the loop and produce a complicated chain of `if` statements (your method 3).

In the comments, the C++11 style solution `max({a,b,c,d})` was given by @NathanOliver (which only works in `constexpr` contexts). But in C++1z, the `std::max_element` will also become `constexpr` so that it will be the fully general solution, small or large, runtime or compile-time.

**TL;DR**: don't overthink this, use the Standard Library which does provably minimal amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

Better is a lose term.  As pointed out in the comments

```
max(max(a,b), max(c,d));
```

is very concise however there are 3 function calls.  It is slightly faster code wise but a lot more coding to write something like:

```
if (a>b)
{ 
  if (a>c)
  {
     if (a>d)
     {
         return (a);
     }
  }
}

if (b>a)
{ 
  if (b>c)
  {
     if (b>d)
     {
         return (b);
     }
  }
}
if (c>a)
{ 
  if (c>b)
  {
     if (c>d)
     {
         return (c);
     }
  }
}

if (d>a)
{ 
  if (d>b)
  {
     if (d>c)
     {
         return (d);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: `std::max({a,b,c,d})`

Comment: `max` is commonly implemented as a macro, and even if it isn't, it's probably inlined by modern compilers.

Comment: This code may do more than twice as many comparisons as `std::max` and for some values this code won't reach any of the `return` statements. Just use `std::max` unless profiling shows it's a bottleneck (and it probably isn't).